# bootstrap 4, narrow viewport, navigation escapes to the right - desperate novice needs advice

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design, navbar

Please forgive my ignorance. I'm not really a coder. I'm a laid off graphic designer desperately trying to get my portfolio a little more polished than the wordpress site I had.

I've rebuilt from what Dreamweaver puts in when you start a new page with bootstrap 4. I've managed to get a lot customized with some help on here.

But I've broken something in the process, because it was working well until recently.

When I narrow the page, at some point in between the most narrow and a normal desktop size, the navigation exceed the container. When I view the site on my phone in landscape this is the default. I've taken a screenshot (further below) but I also have linked the site directly below.

Is this a media-query thing? I just don't even know where to look for this issue to resolve it.

[My site, such as it is](https://clareking.net)

Also!

Not as crucial but I'd love to fix.

a. How can I make the black band under the navbar stretch to the entire screen when it is at it's most narrow?

b. Is there a way (that I can manage without screwing things up) to make the container holding my banner and the navigation be black all across at it's most broad?

Thanks in advance!
Clare

[Misbehaving Navbar when narrowed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2ieh.png)

[1.5cm of padding I don't like when at the most narrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyGDP.png)

Comment: Please put enough code into your question for us to see the problem. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Having said that I did look briefly at your site and don't understand why you set a width for the nav container on a media query when at that point the width is too narrow for the whole navbar. Why not go at that point to the hamburger menu?

Comment: @AHaworth


Thanks for looking. I didn't set any widths. Bootstrap and dreamweaver set that as the default when I created the page. And I have no idea which code even effects this behavior. That's how clueless I am. Well, if I did change any of what came in by default it was completely unintentional. 

But I'd be happy to take your advice in this matter. 

It took me forever to figure out what customization I did with much trial and error. I'm terribly afraid to try any trial and error on this problem because I'm afraid I'll break every thing.